# lower semicontinuity and closed graph

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, semicontinuous-functions

I would like to prove that for a LSC function, its epigraph is closed.
I saw some longer proof [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Characterization_of_Lower_Semicontinuity), but why would the following not hold ? :

$f LSC := \liminf f(x_n) \ge f(x)$ when $x_n \rightarrow x$

then $x_n,a_n \rightarrow x,a \implies f(x) \le \liminf f(x_n) \le \liminf a_n = a$

so $x,a \in epi(f)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a streamlined version of the proof in wikipedia. Perhaps it's a bit too streamlined (write it up using quantifiers!). Otherwise it appears perfectly valid to me.

Comment: yeah, i spotted other weird stuff in the article in reference. not to be taken as a reference !